# Silent stat to check file existence

Tags: bash, stat

I'm running a command if a file is present in one line of bash.

Here is what I'm doing for now:

```
$ stat /last_dump.sql && mysql -D my_database < last_dump.sql
```

Is it the right way to do ?

It works fine, but the stat report is outputted

```
  File: '/last_db.sql'
  Size: 42161       Blocks: 88         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 26h/38d Inode: 108         Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    me)   Gid: (    0/    me)
Access: 2016-06-08 08:07:15.886741191 +0000
Modify: 2016-06-08 08:07:06.218593606 +0000
Change: 2016-06-08 08:07:06.218593606 +0000
 Birth: -
```

How can I **not** show this stat report ?

Comment: You can divert `stat` output to `/dev/null`. `stat file >/dev/null`

Comment: See here also for bash way of checking file existence. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: Feel free to add answers. Both seems pretty good for me, I will be happy upvote. I may have a preference for the `/dev/null` since it should work with other shells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use file test operators:

```
[[ -e ./last_dump.sql ]] && mysql -D my_database < ./last_dump.sql
```

See here for more info about these operators: [File test operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)

But if you prefer to use `stat` you can divert its output to `/dev/null`:

```
stat ./last_dump.sql >/dev/null && mysql -D my_database < ./last_dump.sql
```

Notice `./` in the commands above which means current directory.
Also I should note that if you want to make stat completely silent (even in case of errors) divert errors to `/dev/null` as well using `&>/dev/null` or `>/dev/null 2>&1` (have same result).

Comment: No need for `bash` (note that `[[...]]` comes from `ksh`), you can use the standard `[` aka `test` utility in all shells. As in `[ -e ./last_dump.sql ] && ...`. Note that both `[ -e` and the ksh `[[ -e...]]` do a `stat()` system call while GNU `stat` does a `lstat()`. Use `stat -L` as an equivalent to `[ -e` and `[ -e file ] || [ -L file ]` as an equivalent to `stat` without `-L`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for mentioning this. Did not know `[[ ]]` comes from `ksh`

Answer (score 2):

Calling `stat` is only useful to get information that you can't get from basic shell commands, such as a file's modification time or permissions. To just test the existence of a file, use the `test` command, also spelled `[`. This command is built into most shells.

```
if [ -e last_dump.sql ]; then mysql -D my_database < last_dump.sql; fi
```

The test `-e` tests whether the specified file exists; the file can be of any type, including broken symbolic links. If you only want regular files (including symlinks to regular files), use `-f` instead.

Using `[ … ]` is preferable to `stat` for many reasons:

- Calling `stat` just to discard its output is an obfuscated way of testing whether a file exists. Think of the people who will read the code (such as you in six months): `[ -e file ]` plainly says “does `file` exist?”, whereas calling `stat` says “give me the file's metadata” and testing for existence is merely a side effect.
- `[ … ]` is a standard command, whereas `stat` doesn't exist on all Unix variants and has incompatible command line options where it exists. In this specific case it isn't so bad because.you aren't using any command line options.
- `stat` is slower since it's an external command.

You should also refrain from using `&&` when you mean “if”. This too is markedly less readable. It's also less robust since under `set -e` (telling the shell to exit if any program breaks), `[ -e last_dump.sql ] && mysql …` aborts the script if `last_dump.sql` doesn't exist, whereas `if [ -e last_dump.sql ]; then …; fi` keeps going.

Comment: I see. Great answer. I learnt several things here.